# SpringMVC Invoking a global method

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am a beginner in `springMVC` so take it easy on me guys...i am trying to invoke a method every time a user enters my web application **regardless** of the page/place.

I tried `ContextRefreshedEvent` but it only works when the application starts.
Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Define "enters my web application", precisely.

Comment: www.myapplication.com/store
www.myapplication.com/account or www.myapplication.com/store/product..... all of the will invoke the same method before the actual requestMapping invoked

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Do you want something to happen at each HTTP request? When the user logs in? When a HTTP session is created? HTTP is stateless, so the notion of "entering an application" doesn't exist.

Comment: I just want to set a specific cookie when the user enters my application.. i don't know how yet.

Comment: So, at each HTTP request, if there is no cookie in the request, you want to add one, is that what you want? That's what servlet filters, or spring mvc interceptors, are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example would be

```
public class MyInterceptoor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, 
               HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

It is required to wire interceptor in your config.

```
  <mvc:interceptors>
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/myproject/**"/> 
            <bean class="com.mvc.myproject.MyInterceptoor" />
        </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>
```

[Spring Documentation HandlerInterceptorAdapter](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Interceptor – HandlerInterceptor.

http://www.journaldev.com/2676/spring-mvc-interceptor-example-handlerinterceptor-handlerinterceptoradapter

Answer (score 0):

For SpringBoot you can do this. Make a HandlerInterceptorAdaptor

```
@Component
public class AccessInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)  {
        System.out.println("preHandled for controller = " + handler);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Add it to a Spring WebMvcConfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    AccessInterceptor accessInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(accessInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/**");
    }
}
```

Enjoy ...